# PHPMailer no me envía los datos del formulario

Tags: php, ajax, formularios, phpmailer, hosting

la otra vez vine aquí preguntando como podía hacer para que me lleguen los mails de phpmailer y pude resolver la cuestion. Hoy vengo para pedirles ayuda porque me llega el mail pero no la informacion del mismo, digo, solicito un nombre y apellido, un correo electronico y un mensaje pero no me llegan.

En el body puse codigo html para que quedara mejor a la vista y sí me lee el codigo html pero no las variables. para solucionarlo intenté con un require pero no funcionó. Cabe aclarar que el formulario es vía ajax.

Formulario HTML

```
                <form name="formulario" method="post" class="formulario" id="formulario" action="../PHPMailer-master/enviarCorreo.php"> 
                    <div>
                        <ul class="success" id="success"></ul>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" required id="nombre" class="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Name:" minlength="3" maxlength="15">
                    <input type="text" required id="apellido" class="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Lastname:" minlength="2" maxlength="50">
                    <input type="email" required name="mail" id="mail" class="mail" placeholder="Mail:">
                    <textarea name="texto" required id="texto" class="textarea" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Tell us your project..." minlength="50"></textarea>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn-send" id="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
                    <div>
                        <ul class="error" id="error"></ul>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Archivo Ajax

```
$('#formulario').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let formulario = $(this).serialize();
    let nombre = $('#nombre').val(),
        apellido = $('#apellido').val(),
        correo = $('#mail').val(),
        text = $('#texto').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "../enviarCorreo.php",
            data: {name: nombre, lastname: apellido, email: correo, texto: text},
            success: function(data){
                $('#formulario').trigger('reset');
                alert('The form has been sent successfully!');
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert('The form could not be sent')
            },  
        })  
});
```

Formulario PHP

```
<?php
require 'views/index-view.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $nombre = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $apellido = htmlspecialchars($_POST['lastmail'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $correo = $_POST['email'];
    $texto = $_POST['texto'];
}
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = '***';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = '***';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '***';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('***');
    $mail->addAddress('***');     // Add a recipient             

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = "Correo enviado desde Programmark.com";
    $mail->Body    = "<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <h3>Nombre: $nombre</h3>
        <br>
        <h3>Apellido: $apellido</h3>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h3>Correo: $correo</h3>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h3>Mensaje: </h3>
        <p>$texto</p>
    </body>
    </html>";
    $mail->send();
```

Por ultimo esto me aparece en el `console.log(data)` cada vez que doy click al enviar

```
2021-02-16 14:01:56 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: *** ESMTP Exim 4.93 #2 Tue, 16 Feb 2021 08:01:56 -0600 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: EHLO programmark.com<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: *** Hello programmark.com [192.185.4.32]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS250 HELP<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: STARTTLS<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: EHLO programmark.com<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 2*** Hello programmark.com [192.185.4.32]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250 HELP<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: AUTH LOGIN<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 334 ***<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: [credentials hidden]<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 334 ***<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: [credentials hidden]<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 235 Authentication succeeded<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: MAIL FROM:&lt;tudomini@dominio.com&gt;<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 250 OK<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: RCPT TO:&lt;tudomini@dominio.com&gt;<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 250 Accepted<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: DATA<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 354 Enter message, ending with &quot;.&quot; on a line by itself<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: Date: Tue, 16 Feb 2021 08:01:56 -0600<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: To: tudomini@dominio.com<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: From: tudomini@dominio.com<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: Subject: Correo enviado desde dominio.com<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: Message-ID: &lt;AhkxiQcYEySHvNJMeOqvUx9cOn1S1kde1JHFai8@programmark.com&gt;<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.1.5 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: <br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: &lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:     &lt;html&gt;<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:     &lt;body&gt;<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:         &lt;h3&gt;Nombre: &lt;/h3&gt;<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:         &lt;br&gt;<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:         &lt;h3&gt;Apellido: &lt;/h3&gt;<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:         &lt;br&gt;<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:         &lt;br&gt;<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:         &lt;h3&gt;Correo: &lt;/h3&gt;<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:         &lt;br&gt;<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:         &lt;br&gt;<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:         &lt;h3&gt;Mensaje: &lt;/h3&gt;<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:         &lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:     &lt;/body&gt;<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:     &lt;/html&gt;<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: <br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: .<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 250 OK id=1lC0vM-002irn-Rm<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: QUIT<br>
2021-02-16 14:01:56 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 221 *** closing connection<br>
```

Agradecería mucho que me ayuden a ver por qué no me llega la info del formulario cada vez que se envía el mismo.

Comment: Defines las variables solo si existe `$_POST['submit']`, pero no estás enviando `submit` por AJAX. Quita ese condicional y debe funcionar correctamente.

Comment: Aquí ya estarías serializando todo el formulario: `let formulario = $(this).serialize();` prueba a mandar esa variable como parámetro `data` de tu petición Ajax: **`data: formulario,`** en vez de los valores que recoges a mano sin necesidad. En tu variable `formulario` sí deberia ir un valor para `submit` porque es parte de tu formulario, pues como dice @Triby en la forma de enviar los datos actualmente no estás enviando nada asociado a una clave `submit`, por tanto, esta codición nunca se cumple: `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`